# Python For Loop Optimisation with Two Lists of Sentence Compares

Tags: python, python-2.7, performance, for-loop, revit

I have some python code that is working, but takes awhile to run.  I'm pretty sure it can be optimized by re-arranging the for loops or using functions but my attempts have produced incorrec results.

**Project Info:**

python version = Iron Python 2.7 (Revit Dynamo)

**listMaster** = master list of all available sentences

**List1** = a second list of sentences to compare against listMaster

**List2** = a third list of sentences to compare against listMaster

**Current Workflow:**

1. Loop through List1
2. Loop through each item in listMaster
3. Use SequenceMatcher Ratio to get matches based of ratio
4. Repeat Above for List2, List3, etc

   ```
   # Compare Excel Serious Warnings with All Revit Data
   for itemExcel in warnSeriousExcelData:
       for itemRvt in revitData:
           if SequenceMatcher(None, itemRvt, itemExcel).ratio() > 0.9:
               seriousLstCount = seriousLstCount + 1
               srsData.append(itemExcel)
   # Compare Excel Troublesome Warnings with All Revit Data
   for itemExcel in warnTroublesomeExcelData:
       for itemRvt in revitData:
           if SequenceMatcher(None, itemRvt, itemExcel).ratio() > 0.9:
               troubleLstCount = troubleLstCount + 1
               troubleData.append(itemExcel)
   # Compare Excel Bothersome Warnings with All Revit Data
   for itemExcel in warnBothersomeExcelData:
       for itemRvt in revitData:
           if SequenceMatcher(None, itemRvt, itemExcel).ratio() > 0.9:
               botherLstCount = botherLstCount + 1
               botherData.append(itemExcel)
   # Compare Excel Benign Warnings with All Revit Data
   for itemExcel in warnBenignExcelData:
       for itemRvt in revitData:
           if SequenceMatcher(None, itemRvt, itemExcel).ratio() > 0.89:
               benignLstCount = benignLstCount + 1
               benignData.append(itemExcel)
   # Compare Excel Unrecoverable Warnings with All Revit Data
   for itemExcel in warnUnrecoverExcelData:
       for itemRvt in revitData:
           if SequenceMatcher(None, itemRvt, itemExcel).ratio() > 0.8:
               unrecoverLstCount = unrecoverLstCount + 1
               unrecoverData.append(itemExcel)
   ```

See Image of Data if it helps.
[Data Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYh6q.png)

I'm thinking to maybe speed up the iteration process, to maybe flip the for loops.  So the top loop would be entire listMaster, then I would check each List1, List2 within that for loop?  But I don't know if this again is the fastest approach?

Any help on this would be great.  Again I only have Python 2.7 so I can't use some of the new features in 3.5 etc.

**Updated to run reduce the loop length but still runs slow.**

```
for itemRvt in revitData:
    for itemExcel in warnSeriousExcelData:
        if SequenceMatcher(None, itemRvt, itemExcel).ratio() > 0.9:
                seriousLstCount = seriousLstCount + 1
                srsData.append(itemExcel)
    for itemExcel in warnTroublesomeExcelData:
        if SequenceMatcher(None, itemRvt, itemExcel).ratio() > 0.9:
                troubleLstCount = troubleLstCount + 1
                troubleData.append(itemExcel)
    for itemExcel in warnBothersomeExcelData:
        if SequenceMatcher(None, itemRvt, itemExcel).ratio() > 0.9:
                botherLstCount = botherLstCount + 1
                botherData.append(itemExcel)
    for itemExcel in warnBenignExcelData:
        if SequenceMatcher(None, itemRvt, itemExcel).ratio() > 0.89:
            benignLstCount = benignLstCount + 1
            benignData.append(itemExcel)
    for itemExcel in warnUnrecoverExcelData:
        if SequenceMatcher(None, itemRvt, itemExcel).ratio() > 0.8:
            unrecoverLstCount = unrecoverLstCount + 1
            unrecoverData.append(itemExcel)
```

Matt

Comment: One of the improvement I can think of to loop through `listMaster` only once and inside that separate loops for each Lists. That way time taken can be significantly reduced.

Comment: Updated, but it still runs really slow. Any other thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: It looks like the code you have works as in intended, but is a bit slow. If that observation is correct - you might have more luck at codereview.stackexchange.com. Either way, you should check out cProfile or any other python profiler. It will help you make an informed decision about what's happening.

Comment: great thank you.  I'm also looking to translate the code to C# to see if it runs faster in this environment.

Comment: I do not believe porting to C# will help. Python is fast. What would help more would be if you explained better in short and simple English words what you are trying to achieve. That would say more than the code.

Comment: How many members i each of these lists?

Answer (score 0):

To look up data entries efficiently multiple times, you should not use a list to store them, but a dictionary or hash table. An unsorted list forces you to iterate of the whole thing for each lookup. A dictionary or hash table is much faster. Thousands of times faster, with many entries. Convert  your `warnXyzExcelData` collections to dictionaries and all will be fine. Very simple to fix. Good luck and have fun!